# Entity Framework TPT Inheritance Subtypes

Tags: c#, entity-framework

How can i determine the subtype of an entity with a TPT-Inhertiance?

If i have a base class Person and two subclasses Manager and Customer, it should be possible to query all persons and then group by their subclasses through using the GetType-Method, yet the returned type is always person. E.g.:

```
var persons = ctx.Persons.ToList();

var managers = persons.Where(x => x.GetType() == typeof(Manager)).ToList();
```

Comment: Try just  (Where(x=>x.isTypeOf(Manager))...

Comment: Sry, I should have formulated my question more precisely. I want the managers list to contain actual manager objects.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Select:

```
var managers = ctx.Persons.OfType<Manager>().ToList();
```

also useful if you don't know what you have got

```
var persons = ctx.Persons.ToList();
Type modelType = persons.First().GetType();
if (modelType.BaseType == typeof(Manager))
{
    ((Manager)persons.First()).GiveNeilAPayRise = true;
}
```

Comment: What if i get a random person and don't know what type it is. Casting it to it's subtype doesn't work properly. var manager = persons.First() as Manager